# Choosing a cluster validation measure for graph clustering algorithm

Tags: classification, clustering, validation

I am currently solving a clustering problem. Objects to be clustered are represented as sparse vectors in R^N, N=10. The number of objects is about 1kk. To cluster, I build a graph keeping the largest similiarities between objects and use modularity-based Louvain method.

The problem is, I do not understand how to validate the resulting clusters. I need an internal validation metric which will be computable (O(N^2) is not feasible) and suitable for arbitrary cluster shapes (I have a prior knowledge that clusters are not spherical by all means, though I don't know their count).

The question is: how do I choose a validation metric for my case? Ideally, it is graph-based (though I cannot find such a metric), allows for random cluster shape and computationally as simple as possible.

**What I tried:**

1. Silhouette score. Not feasible due to computation issues.
2. Calinski–Harabasz index. Not feasible, because it features cluster centroids,
   implying that resulting clusters are supposed to be spherical.

**What I didn't try and also don't want to try**

3. Dunn Index. Not feasible, because it features cluster centroids,
   implying that resulting clusters are supposed to be spherical. Also
   I have doubts regarding computational complexity.
4. Density based cluster validation as in [https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/~zimek/publications/SDM2014/DBCV.pdfarticle](https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/%7Ezimek/publications/SDM2014/DBCV.pdfarticle) . Not feasible, because the computation is at least O(N^2), probably even more complex.
5. Modularity, it obviously doesn't make sense since we are optimising it.
6. Dimensionality reduction and K-means clustering.

Thanks in advance.